# Omniauth issues in rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, omniauth

I have followed a screen cast form ryan bates railscast and every thing is working fine except when i change my methods like as follows:

from

```
      def create
       omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
       current_user.authentications.create(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid =>         omniauth["uid"])
       flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
       rescue Exception => e
       # Just spit out the error message and a backtrace.
       render :text => "<html><body><pre>" + e.to_s + "</pre><hr /><pre>" +    e.backtrace.join("\n") + "</pre></body></html>"
    end
```

to

```
  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    current_user.authentications.create(omniauth['provider'], omniauth["uid"])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
  rescue Exception => e
    # Just spit out the error message and a backtrace.
    render :text => "<html><body><pre>" + e.to_s + "</pre><hr /><pre>" + e.backtrace.join("\n") + "</pre></body></html>"
    end
```

i keep getting undefined method `stringify_keys' for "twitter":String` but every thing works fine the first way. any ideas here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed:

```
current_user.authentications.create(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid =>         omniauth["uid"])
```

to:

```
current_user.authentications.create(omniauth['provider'], omniauth["uid"])
```

You will get this error in any rails app as you are not specifying which fields to allocate the values to.
An example (from one of my apps):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > User.create("a", "b")
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "a":String
```

I think you meant the following:

```
user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
```

Comment: this is the same way it was done in the railscasts episode. or am i missing something

Comment: I am sorry, I don't really know what you are trying to do.  What is wrong with the first method?

Comment: nothing just wanted to flow the tutorials way of authentication via twitter cos thats what i am trying to do

Comment: Please link to the screencast and I will check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much now i understand the whole thing

Comment: It says, undefined method `create_with_omniauth'. Where this method is defined ?